# Mysql Order By where alpha numeric

Tags: mysql

Hi have a result which returns as follows

```
ORDER BY ProductCode ASC    

CU522-15
CU522-17
CU522-18
CU522-19
CU522-4
```

I am trying to get cu522-4 to be first and not last .
I can't change the ProductCode as it needs to match another system.
Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY LENGTH(ProductCode), ProductCode
```

CU522-4 will be first because it has less characters

The others will be sorted normally

Comment: Perfect ! Works 'universally' with all they product codes

Answer (score 3):

Going on the assumption it's always '-' this should work:

```
    SELECT   *
FROM     table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(ProductCode,LOCATE('-',ProductCode)+1) AS SIGNED)
```

Use POSITION to find the '-', SUBSTRING to grab the number after it, and CAST to make it a comparable value.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that your product code prefix is not always the same length, you can do:

```
order by substring_index(ProductCode, '-', 1),
         substring_index(ProductCode, '-', -1) + 0;
```

The `+ 0` does a numeric conversion of the value, which is what you want for sorting.